# How to iterate over values of one list, change that with a function and add that to a second list?

Tags: python, list

I have this list of temperatures:

```
temp_data =  [19, 21, 21, 21, 23, 23, 23, 21, 19, 21, 19, 21, 23, 27, 27, 28, 30, 30, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 34,
         34, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 36, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 32, 30, 30, 30, 28, 28, 27, 27, 27, 23, 23,
         21, 21, 21, 19, 19, 19, 18, 18, 21, 27, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 37, 37, 37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39,
         41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 39, 39, 37, 37, 36, 36, 34, 34, 32, 30, 30, 28, 27, 27, 25, 23, 23, 21, 21,
         19, 19, 19, 18, 18, 18, 21, 25, 27, 28, 34, 34, 41, 37, 37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 41, 41, 39, 39, 39,
         39, 39, 41, 39, 39, 39, 37, 36, 34, 32, 28, 28, 27, 25, 25, 25, 23, 23, 23, 23, 21, 21, 21, 21,
         19, 21, 19, 21, 21, 19, 21, 27, 28, 32, 36, 36, 37, 39, 39, 39, 39, 39, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41, 41,
         41, 41, 41, 39, 37, 36, 36, 34, 32, 30, 28, 28, 27, 27, 25, 25, 23, 23, 23, 21, 21, 21, 19, 19,
         19, 19, 19, 19, 21, 23, 23, 23, 25, 27, 30, 36, 37, 37, 39, 39, 41, 41, 41, 39, 39, 41, 43, 43,
         43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 39, 37, 37, 37, 36, 36, 36, 36, 34, 32, 32, 32, 32, 30, 30, 28, 28,
         28, 27, 27, 27, 27, 25, 27, 27, 27, 28, 28, 28, 30, 32, 32, 32, 34, 34, 36, 36, 36, 37, 37, 37,
         37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 37, 36, 34, 30, 30, 27, 27, 25, 25, 23, 21, 21, 21, 21, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19,
         18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 23, 27, 30, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 34, 34, 34, 34, 34, 36, 36, 36, 36,
         36, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 30, 28, 28]
```

I have imported a module that I created with two functions, to change the temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius and the other to classify into 4 classes according to Celsius.

```
from temp_functions import fahr_to_celsius, temp_classifier
```

So, I also created an empty list where the classified according to Celsius will go:

```
temp_classes =[]
```

and a for loop after that:

the for loop should iterate over all values in temp_data, change them via

fahr_to_celsius function, and than append them to the empty list temp_celsius.

```
for t in temp_data:
    temp_celsius = []
    temp_celsius.append(fahr_to_celsius(t))
```

Issue: I just get the first value. I tried range, len, =+1 and several other but no luck.

EDIT:
Adding info from OP comment:

This is an assignment that I am working on:

> Iterate over the Fahrenheit temperature values in the temp_data list
>   (one by one) and inside the loop: Create a new variable called
>   temp_celsius in which you should assign the temperature in Celsius
>   using the fahr_to_celsius function to convert the Fahrenheit
>   temperature into Celsius. Create a new variable called temp_class in
>   which you should assign the temperature class number (0, 1, 2, or 3)
>   using the temp_classifier function Add the temp_class value to the
>   temp_classes list

Answer (score 7):

Another strategy would be to use a Python list comprehension:

`temp_celsius = [fahr_to_celsius(t) for t in temp_data]`

Comment: Thank you. I will try that too. Got myself several hours of learning now.

Answer (score 5):

You are creating a new list at each iteration. move the creation of the list outside of the for loop :

```
temp_celsius = []
for t in temp_data:
    temp_celsius.append(fahr_to_celsius(t))
```

Comment: Thanks. But as this is an assignment that I am working on. """Iterate over the Fahrenheit temperature values in the temp_data list (one by one) and inside the loop:
Create a new variable called temp_celsius in which you should assign the temperature in Celsius using the fahr_to_celsius function to convert the Fahrenheit temperature into Celsius.
Create a new variable called temp_class in which you should assign the temperature class number (0, 1, 2, or 3) using the temp_classifier function
Add the temp_class value to the temp_classes list"""

Comment: @MatijaKordic You should add that info to the question.  This answer is correct based on the information you gave.

Comment: But also we can't do your homework for you; take this answer and work with it to see if you can apply it to your problem.

Comment: I know that the answer is correct. I didn't said that it wasn't. Just still learning to write comments here as enter means add comment... Thanks Cid and @thumbtackthief not doing my homework, I have a master degree, just started learning independently python and I have no one to ask since the course is on git and it can be accessed but I cannot ask anything since I am not a part of their university. So, I wanted to know how.

Comment: Anyway, I apologise to all. Will work on my structuring.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do this using `map` although some folks don't consider this to be "pythonic"

`map()` maps the function to each item in an iterable and takes the form of

```
map(function, iterable) #where an iterable is a list, set, tuple
```

It is essentially the same as the list comprehension.

python3:

```
temp_celcius = list(map(fahr_to_celsius, temp_data)) # explicitly call it a list
```

python2:

```
temp_celcius = map(fahr_to_celsius, temp_data) # interpreted as a list
```

Comment: Thanks. Never heard of this. I'll definitely play around with it to understand its function.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider to use `pandas` to have a table view

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"fahr":temp_data})

df["celsius"] = df["fahr"].apply(fahr_to_celsius)
# or
df["celsius"] = fahr_to_celsius(df["fahr"])
# or (even faster)
df["celsius"] = fahr_to_celsius(df["fahr"].values)
```

Comment: Thank you. Will try that too. Am a complete newbie so learning different ways of doing something is great.